# Running MS SQL Server DB for Ubuntu PHP site

Tags: ubuntu, sql-server, virtualhost, hosting

I'm going to be developing a php site (actually more of a application), but the standards and restriction of what I'm building make MS SQL Server the most appropriate DB solution (will also be running things like SSRS).

So what would be the best way to do this in terms of performance and maintainability?

An obvious solution is to run a virtual machine on the same physical machine as the web server.  I haven't yet picked a hosting solution and I know this will eliminate any of the simpler/cheaper hosting solutions, since this will require much more configuration than they'll allow.

I also read in answer to a somewhat similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5591119/550595) that dual booting was an option.  What is this?  The only dual booting I'm familiar with is having the option to boot to either OS, not run both concurrently.

How big of a performance hit will I take if I choose to host the DB on a separate machine all together?  Or if I elect to have both servers hosted through the same host?

I really don't want to go the route of running the web app and php on MS Server, so that's pretty much out of the question.  If push came to shove, I suppose I could just have a MySQL DB on the same machine then replicate that DB on a different MS SQL Server machine.  Of course any reports or data import/export wont be real-time.

So any advice or suggestions is really appreciated.  Luckily I'm still in the early planning phase and have time to consider different options.

Comment: Are you sure PHP is the right language for this and that Ubuntu is the right operating system? If you have to deal with Microsoft technologies, you probably shouldn't be using either PHP or Ubuntu.

Comment: PHP and MS SQL get along fine (there's a module for it), and this all runs correctly on any Linux flavor. I'd highly recommend against Ubuntu for production work, though.

Comment: @MichaelHampton , php is the language I'm developing in, it's not negotiable.

Comment: @NathanC, yeah, I've worked with php and MS SQL before so I know they play nice.  My question is regarding server infrastructure and what would be the optimal setup, mainly in terms of performance, if I elected to use both.